# PHP switch isnt working

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

```
<body>
    <?php

        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            switch($_GET['page']) {
                case "domov": include ("index.php"); break;
                case "ponuka": include ("pages/ponuka.html"); break;
                case "akcie": include ("pages/akcie.html"); break;
                case "kontakt": include ("pages/kontakt.html"); break;
                default: include ("index.php"); break;
            }
        }
        else  {
            include("index.php");
        }
    ?>

    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <ul class="first">
                <li><a href="index.php?page=domov">Domov</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=ponuka">Ponuka pizze</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div>
                <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=akcie">Akcie</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have a issue using php switch to swap my pages, for example when I hit "kontakt" (contact) button , up in browser it shows .../index.php?page=kontakt but content of kontakt.html wont appear. Maybe its easy to solve for you, but Im new in programming and I cant handle this. Thanks for help.

.. sorry for my lame english language skills

edit1: Maybe its important to mention that if i hit "ponuka pizze" / "kontakt" / "akcie" its still shows content of index.php

edit2: i changed my code and now it looks like you can see it but it doesnt work still, issue is same as in edit1

Comment: `kontakt` !== `Kontact`

Answer (score 3):

Those values are case sensitive. So `Kontakt` is not equal to `kontakt`:

```
switch($_GET['page']) {
  case "domov": include ("index.php"); break;
  case "ponuka": include ("pages/ponuka.html"); break;
  case "akcie": include ("pages/akcie.html"); break;
  case "kontakt": include ("pages/kontakt.html"); break;
  default: include ("index.php"); break;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Not yet! Making the drive to the office now. THEN  I'll finally get my coffee!

Comment: You're missing something else though. ;)  the thing in `index.php?=page=kontakt` - `=` <= Xpage

Comment: Same, it didnt help :/

Comment: OP changed the question/code. It's now *"it shows `.../index.php?page=kontakt`"* - I'm glad I didn't touch this one.

Comment: I actually posted my answer just before I walked out the door. :) And I did notice the incorrect URL but assumed that was just a typo when posting the question. Looks like I guessed right. But it also looks like this may go deeper than I originally thought.

Comment: [`See this comment I left to the OP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178319/php-switch-isnt-working#comment41045605_26178371) - path.

Answer (score 2):

need to remove `=` from `=page`  from url then you will get `$_GET['page']` and make sure have proper matching string in switch

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    switch($_GET['page']) {
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, your url is a bit off:

```
index.php?=page=kontakt
          ^
```

This should be:

```
index.php?page=kontakt
```

> I have a issue using php switch to swap my pages, for example when I hit "kontakt" (contact) button , up in browser it shows **`.../index.php?=page=kontakt`**

I do not know which url you are really using but just make sure that you have the same value either with upper case letter or lower case letter first that corresponds to the cases:

```
<li><a href="index.php?page=kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
case "kontakt": include ("pages/kontakt.html"); break;

// or

<li><a href="index.php?page=Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
case "Kontakt": include ("pages/kontakt.html"); break;
```

Comment: OP changed the question/code. It's now *"it shows `.../index.php?page=kontakt`"* - Glad I didn't touch this one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah now were all confused whats the real case

Comment: simply, when I hit any buttton, it shows only content of index.php and it isnt including kontakt.html, akcie.html or ponuka.html

Comment: @Dedo looking at whats posted, i don't much more that would cause this not to work fine. the only thing i can point out is the path of those files if they really are indeed correct

Comment: one friend told me already this but path is correct , I checked it many times, I dont know what I have bad

Comment: It's a path issue. @Dedo I tested your code using echos in place of the includes and it worked fine. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which will signal errors found.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is Ghost and @Dedo . Is including `index.php` in `case "domov": include ("index.php"); break;` and setting as the default, while the main page's filename is named `index.php`. So, it's including it in different parts of the site. Therefore would need to call the file a different name. I.e.: `menu.php?page=Kontakt`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah i never thought of that actually, they are all in the same page which really doesn't make sense

Comment: That's the only conclusion I can make out of all this.

Comment: Could you please edit my question? Im not sure if I understand where I have to replace it.